# Angular 10: How to remove comments from vendor.js in production?

Tags: angular-cli

I have an Angular 10 project. If I compile it with --prod, I have vendor.js about 4,7Mb. I've looked into it and realized that there are a lot of functions in it with huge comments:
[image: Comment Excample]

How to produce vendor.js without them?

I've tried removeComments option. But it seems to work only for main.js.